# Получение кодов Soundex из колонки с данными

Tags: sql

Всем привет, возможно ли сделать такой запрос в SQL: есть колонка с именами допустим FirstName, нужно получить код soundex для каждого имени в колонке и записать эти кода в колонку FirstNamesdx?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: если ваша СУБД имеет функцию возвращающую soudex то почему бы нет? для mysql и sqlserver что-то вроде `update tableName set firstNameSdx = soundex(FirstName)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

такие СУБД как mysql, sqlserver, oracle имеют функцию `soundex` из коробки. в postgresql она есть доп. модулях.

так что в целом ваша задача сводится к

```
UPDATE  yourTableName SET FirstNameSdx = soundex(firstName)
```

правда, вопрос в том, что в основном это работает с английским языком.

Comment: большое спасибо! Все получилось. у меня база на английском поэтому все хорошо!